# Place images into different sectors of a circle(Titanium)

Tags: image, titanium, pivot, geometry, sector

I have an image of a circle divided into *n* sectors in Titanium. Now inside each sector I need to place an image. Each image angle is calculated from the first image which will be pivoted in the center.

How can I do this ? Place the first image with its pivot in the center-top and then place others images at a certain angle distance in other sectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a rotation to each image.

I've done something similar, maybe it can help you. I wanted to put a label in each sector. For this, first I have to create a transparent view that cover more or less the sector, then put the sector in his place rotating it and then put the label inside sector view.

This is the code I use:

```
var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]; 
var angle = 360 / 8;
var rotation = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var sector = Ti.UI.createView({
                backgroundColor : 'transparent',
                width : 25,
                height : circle.height / 2,
                top : 0
            });
    circle.add(sector);

     rotation = rotation + angle*i;
     var matrix = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix()
        matrix = matrix.rotate(rotation);
        var a = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
            transform : matrix,
            duration : 1000,
            autoreverse : false,
            repeat : 0
        });

        a.anchorPoint = {
            x : 0.5,
            y : 0.5
        }

        sector.anchorPoint = {
            x : 0.5,
            y : 0.5
        }

        sector.animate(a);

            // Create a Label.
            var numberLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text : numberArray[i],
                color : '#FF0000',
                font : {
                    fontSize : 26
                },
                textAlign : 'center',
                top : 10
            });

            // Add to the parent view.
            sector.add(numberLabel);


}
```